# Extracting data with "/" character: SQL against Excel

Tags: sql, excel

small issue that is very annoying.

I am running SQL queries against Excel Sheets. In one of them, a column has numeric values containing `/` characters in it like `351694115129/01.08.F1` or `357153215314-__/07.01.F2`.

When running a simple query: `SELECT * FROM [SheetName$];` the data containing `/` are being left outand are not accessible in the data I get back.

Any idea what is causing this issue?

Comment: Check the data definition, if considered numeric, decimal or int. SQL considers any not numerical characters except -,. as invalid and will not read them. 
Try importing the data as varchar and see if that will bringover the data.

Comment: I tried `CAST()`, `CONVERT()` and `STR()`. The first two return an error probably because I am using `OleDB`. I believe conversion of data is also the way to go, but I still can't figure which function to use